# Python, problem with selenium, chrome detach option working in pycharm but not with the final exe version

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, webdriver-manager

this is my first time using this forum, so please bear with me if I make any mistakes.

I recently made a project using python v3.11 and selenium, i DIDN'T want the browser to close after the automatic tasks so i wrote the chromeOptions(): `options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)`

This is the part of the code in which I am having a problem:

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True) #Works with pycharm, but not with pyinstaller
    options.add_argument("--disable-features=PasswordImport")

    #chrome_driver = ChromeDriverManager().install()
    #driver = Chrome(options=options, service=Service(chrome_driver))
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

window.mainloop()
```

this are the libraries i imported:

```
import customtkinter as customtkinter
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

And this last one is the pynstaller command i used to run:
`pyinstaller -w main.py --collect-all customtkinter --collect-data selenium --noconsole --onefile`

Again everything works fine as long as i run the code using pycharm: the browser opens, does all the automatic stuff and then stays open, but when i execute it using the .exe file created by pyinstaller, the browser opens, does what it has to do and then closes automatically.

I tried a lot of different solutions.
For instance using cx_Freeze instead of pyinstaller, or by changing the pyinstaller command:
`pyinstaller --add-data "chromedriver" --add-data "selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.exe" main.py`

`pyinstaller --add-data "selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.exe" --add-data "customtkinter" main.py`

I have also tried using selenium-wire but no results

I look forward to any responses, Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use an executable .exe file? If you run the browser script from the terminal, it stays open as long as the terminal window is open.